# List servlets in a java webapp (running in tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, gwt

I am trying to re-package a relatively big java webapp which I did not code and for which the project configuration was lost.
I setup a first packaging, and deployed it in tomcat. Now to understand it, I'd like to get a list of the servlets that started successfully or failed, with corresponding access url.

- Is there a way to get that list (from some startup log maybe)?

Some details: the webapp uses gwt (which I don't master), I use tomcat7 on ubuntu. I am not against a solution using another servlet container, if practical.

Comment: can you give us more description about the tree folder of your web apps files and dirctories , do you have web.xml for example ?

Comment: Well, I can't share the web.xml content, but it is a quite standard one: one welcome-file which point to a gwt generated html file, several context-param and many servlet and correponding servlet-mapping. What I am not confident is that those are working (some gwt stuff I don't know), and if there are no other.

Comment: As for the project structure, I try to package the webapp with maven and gwt plugin for maven, using default structure (to my understanding)

Comment: You may then need to get some basics of google web toolkit web app structure then

Comment: I don't get the question. I believe GWT is utterly irrelevant to it though, GWT has nothing to do with servlets specifically. The url-pattern you find in the web.xml is your 'access url'. But servlets don't start so I wouldn't know what else you want to check. Perhaps to find servlet classes in your application not yet mapped in the web.xml to an url-pattern?

Comment: @bmscomp I've read about gwt but that's not enough to master it. Now, as I did not code the project, which was done with old gwt version, I don't know all what it is doing, nor how.

Comment: @Gimby Maybe gwt has nothing to do with it, I mention it in case it does. Also, it could make it impossible to use some potential solution.

Comment: @Gimby No, I do want to know which servlet are loaded (i.e. what I meant by 'start'), or fail to be loaded. I can look in the web.xml (I did actually), but I'd feel safer to check what is happening in the end.

Comment: One problem that lead me to this question is that the (gwt generated) page fails to connect to one (gwt annotated) servlet, with 404 error.

Comment: So that would indicate that what I said earlier is actually true: you want to find servlets which are NOT configured in the web.xml. And because they are not configured in the web.xml, they are not assigned to an url-pattern and whatever client wants to make a HTTP call to the url where the servlet is supposed to be mapped to, will get a HTTP 404.

Comment: Alright, I want that too :-) Just my question is about knowing all what is happening on the servlet container side, servlet loaded, failed, etc... I basically try to observe what the code is doing, without having to read all the source, and understanding it.

Comment: Good luck with that, I hope sooner rather than later you will start to care about understanding things. To find servlets not mapped, use an IDE and do a project source search for 'HttpServlet' - all classes extending that class will be servlets. Any of those classes not in your web.xml will be "missing".

Comment: @Gimby, the project in question here has close to 300 java files and 50000 lines of codes, and depends on several home-made jar. It was implemented by several persons over several projects, and has almost no doc. My job is to make it work again (at least part of it) and change only a few things. Understanding it all is just overkill... please don't judge without knowing the context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would write a simple `JSP or ServletContextListener` to read all the `ServletRegistratioins` from the servlet context and display them.

So your JSP/ServletContextListener would read the data from

```
servletContext.getServletRegistrations();
```

and just display it.

### Edit

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/mappings")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7256602549310759826L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

        Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> registrations = req
                .getServletContext().getServletRegistrations();

        for (String key : registrations.keySet()) {
            ServletRegistration registration = registrations.get(key);
            writer.write("Name: " + registration.getName());
            writer.write("<br>Mappings:");
            for (String mapping : registration.getMappings()) {
                writer.write(mapping);
            }
        }

        // of course you can write that to log or console also depending on your
        // requirement.
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with jsp. Could you give more details about the `ServletContextListener` method? I can make such a servlet, but how to output the results?

Comment: Are the registered servlets all the servlets that should be loaded by the servlet context, independently of the way they were declared and if they failed to load?

Answer (score 0):

You can see started modules and paths in Tomcat by double click at Tomcat and see Modules tab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).